# How to invoke a gmail service from google site

Tags: google-apps-script

I read the tutorial, https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/building-sites-app-part2 that uses spreadsheet service in Google sites. The code uses the spreadsheet key. However to access my mail should I use Oauth or something like,

```
var email = String(Session.getUser().getUserLoginId());
```

Can we also use minute trigger when we embed GAS in google sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear. What do you want to do ? Do you want to get the email ID of the user or do you want to access your email.

Session.getUser().getUserLoginId() only returns the login id of the logged in user. And it works only in Google Apps accounts (not consumer accounts).

If you want to access your email, then make use of the Gmail service

Comment: I want to access my email, ya i have used gmail service in spreadsheet. However, google site shows 'Authorization Required' message. I know Session.getUser().getUserLoginId() only returns the login id, i asked if there is something SIMILAR to that for accessing gmail.

Comment: To overcome the Authorization required message, first authorize your script to access your mail by running any function from the script editor

Comment: Since you are new here, if you are happy with an answer, please mark it so. And same with comments too